# How change the appearance of the programme in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

When doing Python or Java programming  or using any other programming language How to change the appearance of the code, meaning as far as I can see, at a time only the appearance of one element(keyword, comment.. etc) can be changed. The appearance of the whole program can not be made bold, italic or change colour. you have to select an element of the programming language eg:- In Java, select keyword and then the appearance of the keywords in a Java Program can be changed But not the appearance of the whole program .

Is there a way to change the appearance of a whole program in Notepad++ or change settings of appearance that influense all the appearance settings of a  programing language  at once without going by changing appearence settings of one by one of the elements

Comment: In Settings > Style Configurator, most of the included language styles have a 'Default' entry, which will change the appearance of all text for the associated language that isn't explicitly styled elsewhere. There's also Global Styles > Global Override, which should affect all text, regardless of the language.

Comment: @boot13 15 you are right concerning the main problem But, By incrementing the font size the only thing that I can see changing is the program expands itself rather than incrementing the font size and making 'Bold'  well it doesn't make any significant effect. When you look very closely you can see only a very faint boldness

Comment: What font are you using? Some fonts don't show much variation at certain sizes. Also, I've found that it's sometimes necessary, when changing font size in Notepad++, to look for other styles in the list where font size is specified and adjust those, in order for line spacing to make sense. Try setting Global Styles > Default Style, which may produce better results.